# How to find out if package allows to redistribute the assemblies?

Tags: dll, tfs-2015

I want redistribute the some assemblies from nuget packages with wix installer.
How can I check if this is allowed.
If is nuget can I assume that it is allowed to redistribute?

My quesion is for some dll-s from next nugets.

- Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient - [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)
- Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client - [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/)
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client - [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client/)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files are redistributable.

> .NET client libraries for Visual Studio Team Services (and TFS)
>
> Overview
>
> For .NET developers building Windows apps and services that integrate
>   with Visual Studio Team Services, client libraries are available for
>   integrating with work item tracking, version control, build, and other
>   services are now available. These packages replace the traditional TFS
>   Client OM installer and make it easy to acquire and redistribute the
>   libraries needed by your app or service.

Refer to this link for details: [.NET client libraries for Visual Studio Team Services (and TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet)